# Doesnt React use autoprefixer to fill in all css prefixes?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have this css code:

```
.footer-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#aadaff, #00aeff);
    display: flex;
}

.footer-wrapper .footer-text-style {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4vh;
    font-family: Courier;
}
```

From what i read, i was under the impression that react used autoprefixer to fill in for css prefixes, however when im running this locally on Chrome, it just doesnt work as the display: flex only works if i hard code it to -mox-flex.
Is there any reason for this?

PS: My package.json on the browser list config:

```
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: React does indeed support Autoprefixing if you are using Create React App. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/post-processing-css/ Something else is running amok, Chrome doesn’t need a prefix for display:flex

Comment: That was my thinking but then why isn't it working here?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you’re getting it to work with your hard coded fix? -mox-flex isn’t a prefix, at least not one I’m aware of.

Comment: i mean i dont know how to elaborate, just if i put display: flex, the flex doesnt work, if i put display: -moz-flex it does. That's why i find this so strange

Comment: `-moz-flex` isn't a standard prefix. I can't find any documentation that lists it as a value any browser accepts, even historically. I assigned it as a value in Chrome and it gave me the strikeout, implying that it is an invalid property value. I would take a look in the devtools and see what it's computed value is. Very likely this isn't a React issue, but some issue with your specific styling, meaning the CSS being generated isn't wrong, the rules being written don't produce the result you think they do.